# Preventing completion handler to be executed synchronously

Tags: arrays, swift, multithreading, networking, concurrency

I'm writing some networking code in Swift that prevents initiating a download that is already in progress. I do this by keeping tracking of the identity of the network request along with the associated completion handlers in an (synchronized) array `A`. When a network call finishes it calls the completion handlers that are associated with that resource and it subsequently removes those handlers from the array `A`.

I want to make sure there is no way for threads to access the array in certain cases. For example, consider the following scenario:

1. A request to download resource `X` is started.
2. Verify whether the request has already been made.
3. Add the completion handler to the array `A`.
4. If request has not been made, start the download.

What if resource `X` was already downloading, and the completion handler for this download interrupts the thread between steps 2 and 3? It has been verified that the request has been made so the download will not be started, but the new completion handler will be added to array `A` which will now never be called.

How would I block this from happening? Can I lock the array for writing while I do steps 2 and 3?

Comment: "keeping tracking of the identity of the network request along with the associated completion handlers in an (synchronized) array " ... Isn't that exactly what a DispatchQueue is? Just submit your jobs on a serial dispatch queue

Comment: `What if resource X was already downloading, and the completion handler for this download interrupts the thread between steps 2 and 3?`. I may be confused but how can the completion handler be running while X is still downloading? Doesn't the completion handlers run after X is done?

Comment: @John, I want all the handlers that wanted to download resource X to be fired. The objects making the requests should be agnostic about this mechanism and just get their completion handlers fires as if they initiated the download, even if another object made the request first.

Comment: @TNguyen: The resource X download could have been initiated already. Then, when another object requests resource X, the completion handler of the previous download could be fired between steps 2 and 3.

Comment: Rather than making them cancellable, you might consider having the client objects just ignore the callbacks if they decide they don't need the results. Also, thanks for sharing what you came up with, but please put it into an answer, not the question.

Comment: Thanks, I did that. Yes, but if the underlying work is costly you still might want to cancel the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm working on the assumption that you want to be able to add multiple callbacks that will all be run when the latest request completes, whether it was already in-flight or not.

Here's a sketch of a solution. The basic point is to take a lock before touching the array(s) of handlers, whether to add one or to invoke them after the request has completed. You must also synchronize the determination of whether to start a new request, **with the exact same lock**.

If the lock is already held in the public method where the handlers are added, and the request's own completion runs, then the latter must wait for the former, and you will have deterministic behavior (the new handler will be invoked).

```
class WhateverRequester
{
    typealias SuccessHandler = (Whatever) -> Void
    typealias FailureHandler = (Error) -> Void

    private var successHandlers: [SuccessHandler] = []
    private var failureHandlers: [FailureHandler] = []

    private let mutex = // Your favorite locking mechanism here.

    /** Flag indicating whether there's something in flight */
    private var isIdle: Bool = true

    func requestWhatever(succeed: @escaping SuccessHandler,
                         fail: @escaping FailureHandler)
    {
        self.mutex.lock()
        defer { self.mutex.unlock() }

        self.successHandlers.append(succeed)
        self.failureHandlers.append(fail)

        // Nothing to do, unlock and wait for request to finish
        guard self.isIdle else { return }

        self.isIdle = false
        self.enqueueRequest()
    }

    private func enqueueRequest()
    {
        // Make a request however you do, with callbacks to the methods below
    }

    private func requestDidSucceed(whatever: Whatever)
    {
        // Synchronize again before touching the list of handlers and the flag
        self.mutex.lock()
        defer { self.mutex.unlock() }

        for handler in self.successHandlers {
            handler(whatever)
        }

        self.successHandlers = []
        self.failureHandlers = []
        self.isIdle = true
    }

    private func requestDidFail(error: Error)
    {
        // As the "did succeed" method, but call failure handlers
        // Again, lock before touching the arrays and idle flag.
    }
}
```

This is so broadly applicable that you can actually extract the callback storage, locking, and invocation into its own generic component, which a "Requester" type can create, own, and use.

Comment: Thanks. That's very helpful. Are there some implication in choosing one locking mechanism over another? Would NSLock do in this case? I will implement your code today and update my question with my (generic) implementation based on your code.

Comment: Does it matter that the lock in the requestDidSucceed might be called on a different thread from which the requestWhatever will be running on? (I assume not). Is there a preference for using NSLock over creating a serial queue and executing the requestWhatever and requestDidSucceed methods on that serial queue? (as was suggested by @JeremyP.)

Comment: _"Does it matter that the lock in the requestDidSucceed might be called on a different thread"_ Nope, that's exactly what it's for. If a lock didn't prevent multithreaded access, it wouldn't be much of a lock. Synchronization via a serial queue is an option too, and this could be transformed to use one if you wanted, but you would have to queue hop in the `requestDidSucceed` and `requestDidFail` methods to make sure the handlers were on an expected thread for their owners.

Comment: I updated my answer with an generic implementation of a Request. I also found I needed a Requester that keeps track of the various requests for me. I was struggling a bit finding the right design pattern. At some point I ran into the problem that I couldn't use a protocol in the Request to tell the Requester that it needed to remove itself from the array since I'm using a generic type. I ended up passing a closure. Not too pretty, but at least it's hidden from the interface.

Comment: Also, I'm not too happy with some of the "should"'s in the code I posted. I would like to protect myself from forgetting to do this or that. Since I wanted the "work" to be very generic, I didn't see any way to implement what I wanted without having the need for some manual callbacks in the work closure.

Answer (score 2):

The simple solution is to run everything on the main thread except the actual downloading. All you need to do is make the completion handler a stub that places a block on the main queue to do all the work.

The pseudo code for what you want is something like

```
assert(Thread.current == Thread.main)
handlerArray.append(myHandler)
if !requestAlreadyRunning)
{
    requestAlreadyRunning = true
    startDownloadRequest(completionHandelr: {
        whatever in
        Dispatch.main.async // This is the only line of code that does not run on the main thread
        {
            for handler in handlerArray
            { 
                handler()
            }
            handlerArray = []
            requestAlreadyRunning = false
        }
    })
}
```

This works because all the work that might result in race conditions and synchronisation conflicts runs on one thread - the main thread and so the completion handler can't possibly be running when you are adding new completion handlers to the queue and vice versa.

Note that, for the above solution to work, your application needs to be in a run loop. This will be true for any Cocoa based application on Mac OS or iOS but not necessarily true for a command line tool. If that is the case or if you don't want any of the work to happen on the main thread, set up a serial queue and run the connection initiation and the completion handler on it instead of the main queue.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Josh's answer I created a generic Request & Requester below. It had a few more specific needs than I described in the question above. I want the Request instance to manage only requests with a certain ID (which I made into a String for now, but I guess this could also made more generic). Different ID's require a different Request instance. I created the Requester class for this purpose.

The requester class manages an array of Requests. For example, one could choose T = UIImage, and ID = image URL. This would give us an image downloader. Or one could choose T = User, and ID = user id. This would get a user object only once, even when requested several times.

I also wanted to be able to cancel requests from individual callers. It tags the completion handler with a unique ID that is passed back to the caller. It can use this to cancel the request. If all callers cancel, the request is removed from the Requester.

(*The code below has not been tested so I cannot guarantee it to be bug free. Use at your own risk.*)

```
import Foundation

typealias RequestWork<T> = (Request<T>) -> ()
typealias RequestCompletionHandler<T> = (Result<T>) -> ()
typealias RequestCompletedCallback<T> = (Request<T>) -> ()

struct UniqueID {
    private static var ID: Int = 0
    static func getID() -> Int {
        ID = ID + 1
        return ID
    }
}

enum RequestError: Error {
    case canceled
}

enum Result<T> {
    case success(T)
    case failure(Error)
}

protocol CancelableOperation: class {
    func cancel()
}

final class Request<T> {
    private lazy var completionHandlers = [(invokerID: Int,
                                            completion: RequestCompletionHandler<T>)]()
    private let mutex = NSLock()
    // To inform requester the request has finished
    private let completedCallback: RequestCompletedCallback<T>!
    private var isIdle = true
    // After work is executed, operation should be set so the request can be
    // canceled if possible
    var operation: CancelableOperation?
    let ID: String!

    init(ID: String,
         completedCallback: @escaping RequestCompletedCallback<T>) {
        self.ID = ID
        self.completedCallback = completedCallback
    }

    // Cancel the request for a single invoker and it invokes the competion
    // handler with a cancel error. If the only remaining invoker cancels, the
    // request will attempt to cancel
    // the associated operation.
    func cancel(invokerID: Int) {
        self.mutex.lock()
        defer { self.mutex.unlock() }
        if let index = self.completionHandlers.index(where: { $0.invokerID == invokerID }) {
            self.completionHandlers[index].completion(Result.failure(RequestError.canceled))
            self.completionHandlers.remove(at: index)
            if self.completionHandlers.isEmpty {
                self.isIdle = true
                operation?.cancel()
                self.completedCallback(self)
            }
        }
    }

    // Request work to be done. It will only be done if it hasn't been done yet.
    // The work block should set the operation on this request if possible. The
    // work block should call requestFinished(result:) if the work has finished.
    func request(work: @escaping RequestWork<T>,
                 completion: @escaping RequestCompletionHandler<T>) -> Int {
        self.mutex.lock()
        defer { self.mutex.unlock() }
        let ID = UniqueID.getID()
        self.completionHandlers.append((invokerID: ID, completion: completion))
        guard self.isIdle else { return ID }
        work(self)
        self.isIdle = false
        return ID
    }

    // This method should be called from the work block when the work has
    // completed. It will pass the result to all completion handlers and call
    // the Requester class to inform that this request has finished.
    func requestFinished(result: Result<T>) {
        self.mutex.lock()
        defer { self.mutex.unlock() }
        completionHandlers.forEach { $0.completion(result) }
        completionHandlers = []
        self.completedCallback(self)
        self.isIdle = true
    }
}

final class Requester<T>  {
    private lazy var requests = [Request<T>]()
    private let mutex = NSLock()

    init() { }

    // reuqestFinished(request:) should be called after a single Request has
    // finished its work. It removes the requests from the array of requests.
    func requestFinished(request: Request<T>) {
        self.mutex.lock()
        defer { self.mutex.unlock() }
        if let index = requests.index(where: { $0.ID == request.ID }) {
            requests.remove(at: index)
        }
    }

    // request(ID:, work:) will create a request or add a completion handler to
    // an existing request if a request with the supplied ID already exists.
    // When a request is created, it passes a closure that removes the request.
    // It returns the invoker ID to the invoker for cancelation purposes.
    func request(ID: String,
                 work: @escaping RequestWork<T>,
                 completion: @escaping RequestCompletionHandler<T>) ->
        (Int, Request<T>) {
        self.mutex.lock()
        defer { self.mutex.unlock() }
        if let existingRequest = requests.first(where: { $0.ID == ID }) {
            let invokerID = existingRequest.request(work: work, completion: completion)
            return (invokerID, existingRequest)
        } else {
            let request = Request<T>(ID: ID) { [weak self] (request) in
                self?.requestFinished(request: request)
            }
            let invokerID = request.request(work: work, completion: completion)
            return (invokerID, request)
        }
    }
}
```